# Generate a color from a string ID in python 2

Tags: python-2.7

Okay, let's try this again,

Is there a way in python to convert a md5 hash into a RGB color value?

I have a no of objects, each with a unique string ID. I want to generate a RGB color value from this ID - a color ID of sorts. So, given the same ID, I get the same color, and only that color. 
I haven't worked much with colors, and at this point I'm drawing a bit of a blank with this. I'll be happy with pointers from folks with relevant knowledge on how to go about his.

This is what I have so far:

```
hash = hashlib.md5(obj_id).hexdigest()
int_val = int(hash, 16)
```

Now what?

Comment: Python doesn't have colors.

Comment: This question needs much more information. For starters, the format of the ID, the format of the color ID, the code you've written to try to do this, and a description of what your code is doing wrong.

Comment: An md5hash has 128 bits, a 'normal' RGB colour value (that you can display) has 24 bits. You cannot encode 128 bits in 24 without throwing away most of the information. The simplest way to do what you are asking would be to split the 128b hash into three parts (discarding 2 bits), and somehow down-sample those to 8-bits each for your RGB values. Because you are losing information, you will not get unique colours for all hashes though. Without code, and a clear problem statement, however, this question is likely to be closed as 'unclear what you are asking'.

Comment: @SiHa, you are right. I guess I need to think this through better. I was able to get a crude implementation, but like you said I had to throw away most of the information & I wasn't particularly happy with what I had.

Comment: I'll close this question now.

Answer (score 1):

After looking around, I found this gist and adapted it for my purposes:
https://gist.github.com/mrkmg/1607621

Posting this here in case it proves to be useful to someone.